# Andengine detect speed of body when it is zero

Tags: android, andengine, velocity

I'm new to developing games for Android. I use andengine library. I want to detect the velocity of the body.

But I will explode the body when the speed of the body is zero. I think I have tried every way: `getLinearVelocity`, `getAngularVelocity`, `len()`, `len2()` methods.

But I haven't found any solution. Please help me. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try to detect velocity as 0? like body.getLinearVelocity == 0? Try to detect if it is lower then some (small) value like body.getLinearVelocity <  0.2

Comment: You can't do that like body.getLinearVelocity == 0. Because getLinearVelocity returns Vector2, not float or int value.

Comment: probably you are right, but the idea was to check not for 0 but small value near zero.

Comment: I am doing like that for now. Thank you for your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have solved my problem myself. Below the code:

if ( Math.abs( body.getLinearVelocity().len() ) > 0.01f )
 {

}

This code helps me. If you face this problem, I think you can use this.